# How to make the current location Accurate using Gmap api v3?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, currentlocation

I make some project for looking nearby location from my current location to my database location.This project run in localhost using XAMPP.

HTML :

```
 <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initMap()">
    <div>
         <label for="raddressInput">Search location:</label>
         <input type="hidden" id="addressInput" size="15" value="kudus" />
        <label for="radiusSelect">Radius:</label>
        <select id="radiusSelect" label="Radius">
          <option value="50" selected>50 kms</option>
          <option value="30">30 kms</option>
          <option value="20">20 kms</option>
          <option value="10">10 kms</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width: 10%; visibility: hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 90%"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  //this code to get current location
  if(!!navigator.geolocation) {

    var map;

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: geolocate,
            content:"<b>Posisi Kamu Sekarang</b>"
        });
        var title = "<b>Posisi Kamu Sekarang</b>";
        var tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: geolocate
      });
        google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(title);
        infoWindow.open(map, tanda);
      });
        markers.push(tanda);
        map.setCenter(geolocate);

    });
<script async defer
    src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&key=Mykey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

When i load this code using public network. it load successfully, the marker and map showing my current location at "kudus". But when i try at my home, using Hotspot connection from my Redmi 4x.My Current location generate to "Semarang".
How to make the current location accurate to my location now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this is useful for you.

Please give your API-key and run this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css1/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.wisdomproperties.com/staging/css1/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>

body {  margin: 0;  }
#map {   width: 100%;   height: 100%; position: relative; }
.container{ margin: 0 auto; width: 70%; height: 500px; }
.placesCont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 15px 10px 0;
}
.placesCont ul li{ cursor:pointer; }
.placesCont ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #66af5d;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(2) a{ background:#1459d8;}
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(2) span{ background:#1459d8;}
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(3) a{  background:#bd6214;}
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(3) span{  background:#bd6214;}
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(4) a{  background:#7e8665; }
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(4) span{  background:#7e8665; }
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(5) a{ background:#936bbf; }
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(5) span{ background:#936bbf; }
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(6) a{ background:#f44336; }
.placesCont ul li:nth-child(6) span{ background:#f44336; }

.placesCont ul li a i { border: 3px solid #fff;  width: 42px; height: 42px; border-radius: 50%; padding: 10px 0; text-align: center;  margin-left: -2px; }

.placesCont ul li span {    display: inline-block;    background: #66af5d;    padding: 11px 40px;    margin-left: -29px;    border-radius: 70px;    z-index: -1;    position: relative;    width: 190px;    text-align: center;    text-transform: capitalize;  color: #fff;    top: 1px; }


    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div class="placesCont">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li value="school" icon = https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-pushpin.png class="placeBtn" >
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-car active" title="parking"></i></a>
                        <span>parking</span>
                    </li>
                    <li value="restaurant" icon = http://182.156.201.194/wisdom_properties/images/icons/resturant.png class="placeBtn">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"  title="restaurant"></i></a>
                        <span>restaurant</span>
                    </li>
                    <li value="travel_agency" icon = http://182.156.201.194/wisdom_properties/images/icons/travelagncy.png class="placeBtn">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-bus"  title="travel_agency"></i></a>
                        <span>travel agency</span>
                    </li>
                    <li value="hospital" icon = http://182.156.201.194/wisdom_properties/images/icons/hospital.png class="placeBtn">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"  title="hospital"></i></a>
                        <span>hospital</span>
                    </li>
                    <li value="store" icon = http://182.156.201.194/wisdom_properties/images/icons/store.png class="placeBtn">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"  title="store"></i></a>
                        <span>store</span>
                    </li>
                    <li value="bank" icon = http://182.156.201.194/wisdom_properties/images/icons/bank.png class="placeBtn">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"  title="bank"></i></a>
                        <span>bank</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your-Kye&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    <script>
        initialLocation = {lat: 13.001637, lng: 80.257942};
        map = document.getElementById('map');
        mapMarkers = [];
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        function initMap() {

          map = new google.maps.Map(map, {
            center: initialLocation,
            zoom: 15
          });

      setMarker(initialLocation, "Project Loction", "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-pushpin.png");
      createRadiusCircle();

          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           var places = {
           restaurant:'restaurant',
           bank:'bank',
           store:'store',
           parking:'parking',
           travel_agency:'travel_agency',


          }

            var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-pushpin.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-pushpin.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-pushpin.png'
          }
        };


          getPlaces(places,icons);


                  }

    function createRadiusCircle()
    {
      var radiusCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#64B5F6',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map : map,
        center : initialLocation,
        radius : 1000
      });
    }

       function setMarker(place, placeName, icon)
       {

            var icon = {
    url: icon, // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), 

};

          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon : icon,
            map : map,
            position : place,
            zoom : 15
          });
          mapMarkers.push(marker);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(placeName);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
       }
       function clearMarkers()
       {
          for (var index = 0; index < mapMarkers.length; index++) 
          {
      if(index)
      {
        mapMarkers[index].setMap(null);
      }

          }
          mapMarkers = []
       }

       function getPlaces(place,icon)
       {
          services =  new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          var object = {
            location : initialLocation,
            radius : '1000',
            type : place

          }
         var callBackFunction = function(results, status)
         {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
            {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
              {
                var place = results[i];
                setMarker(place.geometry.location, place.name,place.icon);
              }
            }
         };

         services.nearbySearch(object, callBackFunction);
       }


       $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".placeBtn i").off("click").on("click", function(){
          $('.active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });



         $(".placeBtn").off("click").on("click", function(){
           clearMarkers();
           var place = $(this).attr("value");
           var icon = $(this).attr("icon");

           getPlaces(place,icon);
         });
       })

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Nachimuthu.R

Comment: i have the api, but hide it anyway.and can explain some with your code for fix my problem?